# ImportError: cannot import name 'pytext_config_from_json' from 'pytext.config.serialize'

Tags: pytext

I'm trying to fine-tune XLM-R model by following this [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/facebookresearch/pytext/blob/master/demo/notebooks/xlm_r_tutorial.ipynb#scrollTo=rN2LhQoPF4fO).

While running the following cell in kaggle notebook

`from pytext.config.serialize import pytext_config_from_json`

I'm getting the error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'pytext_config_from_json' from 'pytext.config.serialize' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytext/config/serialize.py)`

I have installed pytext by

`!pip install --quiet git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytext`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from pytext.config import pytext_config_from_json
```

Comment: still getting the error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'pytext_config_from_json' from 'pytext.config' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytext/config/__init__.py)`

Comment: How did you name your file if its serialize.py then there can be interference with the package/library your trying to import.

Comment: yeah it is named serialize.py